# Cloud SQL PostgreSQL reached max 100 connections but dashboard says only 20

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

I have a Cloud SQL - PostgreSQL (1 vCPUs / 3.75 GB memory) database which can accept up to 100 connections [1]

Maximum active connections from Cloud SQL dashboard was approx. 20 during the peak.
[image: Connections graph]

(`y` axis is number of active connections)

However, according to my Cloud SQL logs, it seems that I reached the maximum connection limit:

```
FATAL:  remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections
```

(This error message was at the same timestamp as the peak in the above graph)

**Is it possible that the number in Cloud SQL dashboard is wrong?**

If not, how can I properly debug this?

My backend is running in Google App Engine and at this time, there was only 2 running instances.

Sources:

- [1] https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/quotas#cloud-sql-for-postgresql-connection-limits

Comment: what about idle connections?

Comment: Where can I find this metric? The Cloud SQL dashboard does not show this number anywhere. Maybe there was 20 active connections but 80 idle ones? Therefore why would my backend want to open more connection if there are so many idle ones?

Comment: if you don't close the connection in your code, (almost) nothing else will close it for you (even if you use a connection pool, you still need to declare that you are done using a connection)

Comment: Sure, my ORM is supposed to handle this for me, I will double check their documentation, thanks for flagging. https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/working-with-prismaclient/connection-management

Comment: Have you confirmed the source of the problem? I agree that if you're not explicitly closing the connections you're opening you might be exceeding the quota and therefore obtaining these errors.